# Printer on wired LAN not accessible from wifi in a differnet subnet

Tags: fortigate, network-access

My network diagram is as follows:

[image: network diag]

The printer on the 2-network responds to pings from the 3-wifi-network for sometime and then just drops out for some reason i can’t figure out.

I have policies on the fortigate firewall to traffic from 3.0 to 2.0 and also reverse with all ports open. I have a server on 2.250 which responds to pings perfectly but not this printer. 
The printer is on a static ip of 2.16.

I have also configured policy routing on the fortigate to force to and from traffic with source and destination addresses 2.0 and 3.0 and vice versa to force the traffic between those two.

My policy config and routers as follows:

```
config firewall policy
    edit 3
        set uuid 2e5c19ea-8776-51e5-f4a0-26880cb5c37b
        set srcintf "internal1"
        set dstintf "internal2"
        set srcaddr "all"
        set dstaddr "all"
        set action accept
        set schedule "always"
        set service "ALL"
        set logtraffic disable
    next
end

config firewall policy
    edit 4
        set uuid 2e75fa22-8776-51e5-a324-5bb10126bbdd
        set srcintf "internal2"
        set dstintf "internal1"
        set srcaddr "all"
        set dstaddr "all"
        set action accept
        set schedule "always"
        set service "ALL"
        set logtraffic disable
    next
end
```

And policy routing to force traffic:

```
config router policy
    edit 2
        set input-device "internal2"
        set src "192.168.3.0/255.255.255.0"
        set dst "192.168.2.0/255.255.255.0"
        set output-device "internal1"
    next
    edit 1
        set input-device "internal1"
        set src "192.168.2.0/255.255.255.0"
        set dst "192.168.3.0/255.255.255.0"
        set output-device "internal2"
    next
end
```

and the interfaces :

```
config system interface
    edit "internal1"
        set vdom "root"
        set ip 192.168.2.1 255.255.255.0
        set allowaccess ping https ssh
        set vlanforward enable
        set type physical
        set alias "LAN"
        set snmp-index 4
    next
end

config system interface
    edit "internal2"
        set vdom "root"
        set ip 192.168.3.1 255.255.255.0
        set allowaccess ping https ssh
        set vlanforward enable
        set type physical
        set alias "WIFI"
        set snmp-index 5
    next
end
```

Any help please.

Comment: When the pings stop, are there any messages in the firewall log?

Comment: @RonTrunk i tried to debug this, the firewall doesn't even "see" the pings coming from the 3.0 PC. I haven't checked the logs exactly, i'll do that. thanks

Comment: When the printer fails, can the two clients still ping each other?  Can the wired client ping the printer?

Comment: @RonTrunk the wired clients can always ping the printer and use it just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is late but finally.

I have now found the answer to it. It’s a weird situation.

I had opened a ticket with Fortinet’s TAC for the printer query which I have posted and he just enabled NAT on the WI-FI interface on which the printer is connected and the issue was resolved.

After this with another client of mine, I faced the same situation this time with an NAS storage device. And voila I had to enable NAT on the interface to which the NAS box was connected to.

For some reason any such device like printers, NAS etc. don’t seem to respond to communication from another subnet on the same fortigate and NAT solves the problem.

The same setup works fine if it was a PC in place of the printer.